# What causes grey, blurry area when pushing and popping UIViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

[image]

This grey and blurry area only show up when pushing or popping view controller. What causes this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by `window` having black background color. Matching `window` and view controllers background colors fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
   [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
   [self.view setAlpha:0];
}
```

Do not forget re set alpha when come back.

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
   [super viewWillAppear:animated];
   [self.view setAlpha:1];
}
```